# Spring Batch process takes too long to finish the task

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

There is a java process, which fires a long running database query to fetch huge number of rows from DB. Then these rows are written to a file.  The query cannot be processed on a chunk basis because of various reasons.

I just wrapped the process in a Spring Batch tasklet and started the job.

Observed that the normal java process is 4 times faster than the Spring Batch Job. I am aware that the above scenario is not suitable for a Spring batch configuration, but just curious to know why the process is slow, when it is made as a Tasklet.

[Edit] Recently I created another batch process ,which contains an ItemProcessor, to validate each item agains a set of data which should be loaded before the job starts. I created a job listener to initialize the set of data from Oracle DB.  The set contains almost 0.2 million records and reading these data takes almost 1.5 hours. So seriously doubt spring batch has some limitation on reading large amount of data in a single shot from DB.

Comment: What kind of jobRepository are you using?If it's a db in another machine, it will create a lot of latency

Comment: Have you done any profiling?  If the code is in a Tasklet, overhead should be virtually nil since there is virtually no state being stored.  I'd also be interested in finding out why chunk based processing isn't an option here.

Comment: @dimzak : I am using JobRepositoryFactoryBean with DB in another machine.    Michael Minella : till now I have not done any profiling.  Not using chunk based processing because the file is an excel or pdf one generated using BIRT API.

Comment: As Michael mentioned, the tasklet approach shouldn't have any overhead. Are you using the same data source & drivers for the Spring Batch app and the plain old app?

Comment: Both are using same driver. But the old query is executed with JDBCTemplate.  Not JPA.